# Random matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I want to create in R 10000 random normal matrices of size n = 6.
The code for one matrix is :

```
n = 6
H = matrix(rnorm(n*n), n,n)
```

But how can I create 10000 matrices in one for loop command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replicate` function is great for running a simple command multiple times.  Turn what you want into either a simple expression or a function and then you can very easily get this to be done multiple times.

```
rmat <- function(n){
  matrix(rnorm(n*n), n, n)
}
out <- replicate(10000, rmat(6))
```

Comment: and if I want to plot the Eigen values of all these matrices ?

Comment: Then that's a different question

Answer (score 0):

If you want them in a list you can try

```
l1 <- lapply(1:10000, # loop 10K times a function that creates your matrix
             function(x, n = 6){ 
               matrix(rnorm(n*n), n,n)
               })
```

Comment: If your comment says 10k you probably shouldn't only loop for 100